# Objective-C Airdrop menu not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiactivityviewcontroller

I am trying to add an share button to my app to share a PDF, I have tried the following:

```
NSArray *objectsToShare = @[@"http://example.com/ios-game-kit-sample.pdf"];

UIActivityViewController *controller = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:objectsToShare applicationActivities:nil];
[self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
```

But I am getting this error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'UIPopoverPresentationController (<_UIAlertControllerActionSheetRegularPresentationController: 0x166fb530>) should have a non-nil sourceView or barButtonItem set before the presentation occurs.'
```

What am I doing wrong ?

I see this solution, but I dont understand what `parentView` is:

```
alertController.popoverPresentationController.sourceView = parentView;
```

Comment: Read the error. It tells you what is wrong. You need to set one of those values on the view controller you are presenting.

Comment: The duplicate is about showing an action sheet instead of an activity view but it's the same basic issue with the same solution.

Comment: The changed parentView to self.view and it worked ! now I just need to figure out the positioning

Comment: @user979331 Positioning is based on the sourceView. Say if you want to show the popover from a button which is located in footer of the screen, pass that buttons view as source view.